# How to select only exact strings from a search in Python?

Tags: python, scrapy

I scrape a website with Scrapy. After that, the user can search the results on my website with algolia. My problem is in the precision of scraping for general results.
For example, when I scrape an item containing "Red wood bed", I scrape all objects with "Red wood bed" and it's accurate.
Then I look for "Red bed". The problem is that "Red wood bed" results are also scraped and I don't want that. I have 10 000 different "searchs" in my scraper.
How can I select strictly "Red bed" to be as accurate as possible in python ?

My first guess is to scrape all and then sort the results:

```
for x in "red wood items":
    if "bed" in "red wood bed":
       remove "result containing bed"
```

But it seems very long. Is there another way in Python ?